# Дублирование моделей sqlalchemy и схем pydantic

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

Я делаю crud аккаунтов пользователей на fastapi. Есть модель:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    login: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(128), nullable=False, unique=True)
    pw: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(128), nullable=False)
```

и мне нужно написать схемы для crud операций,
так должна выглядеть схема для обновления юзера

```
class UpdateUser(BaseModel):
    login: Optional[str]
    pw: Optional[str]
```

Т.к. crud схемы будут практически идентичны модели orm, назревает вопрос: как можно избежать
дублирования моделей и схем? Как по мне это затрудняет рефакторинг в случае изменения модели orm

Comment: Как вариант, можно использовать модуль SQLModel от автора FastAPI: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com

Comment: спасибо, юзал год назад его, но для других целей

Comment: у него нету конфликтов с sqlalchemy 2? sqlmodel использует версию 1.4

Comment: Нет, максимальная версия sqlalchemy прописана 1.4.41. Есть [пулл-реквест](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/pull/563) с добавлением поддержки версии 2, но пока не влит.